# provider: SQL SERVER Interfaces, error: 26 - Error al buscar el servidor o instancia especificada

Tags: c#, base-de-datos

Soy un poco nuevo en esto y tengo un problema.
He creado un sistema con las operaciones basicas, agregar, modificar, eliminar y buscar. Este sistema esta hecho en C# con el programa Visual Studio 2013, la base de datos la cree en SQL SERVER 2008. Ya esta todo terminado y he realizado su intalador.

El problema es que cuando instalo el sistema en otra PC, me marca un error y noce que es.

El error dice lo siguiente:

> Error relacionado con la red o especifico de la instancia mientras se
>   establecia una conexion con el servidor SQL SERVER. No se encontro el
>   servidor o este no estaba accesible. Compruebe que el nombre de la
>   instancia es correcta y que SQL SERVER esta configurado para admitir
>   conexiones remotas (provider: SQL SERVER Interfaces, error: 26 - Error
>   al buscar el servidor o instancia especificada).

Ayuda es urgente. 

Noce si tengo subir la base de datos a un servidor y si es asi como conectarla con el proyecto.

Comment: están en red? recomendación: asigna una IP fija al server. Por cierto, cómo configuras eso? desde un app config? o en el mismo sistema que has hecho?

Comment: No esta en red, la verdad noce, solo configure el app config para conectarme a la base de datos

Comment: Pregunta, el SQL está en tu misma computadora?, si no es así entonces no te podrás conectar nunca.
Además, te recomiendo que edites la pregunta, añadiendo tu configuración, (puedes cambiar la ip que pones en el .config y poner una randon, por si no quieres mostrar tu ip), aunque estoy un bastante seguro de que debe ser asunto de red o ip como dice @fredyfx

Comment: noce != no sé //La palabra noce no está registrada en el Diccionario. Fuente http://dle.rae.es/

Comment: SQL SERVER lo tengo instalado en mi PC, pero en la PC donde quiero instalarlo no tiene SQL SERVER. Y no sé a qué te refieres con agregar mi IP, en mi app.config no agregue ninguna IP.

Comment: ambas comparten internet?

Comment: No, no compartimos internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a ver Ryuzaki, antes que sigas cazando a Kira, analiza lo siguiente:

1. SQL Server está en una computadora X donde también se ha instalado el programa.
2. El programa le has pasado a tu amigo/conocido/contacto y lo ha instalado en una computadora Y.
3. La configuración que está en el AppConfig que apunta a la instancia que se encuentra en la máquina X.
4. Considerando que ni X ni Y comparten la misma red, es imposible que haya una conexión al SQL Server, por lo tanto el error que tienes.

Solución o posibles soluciones

1. Instalar el SQL Server en la máquina Y o en alguna computadora en su red, tener en cuenta que la conexión del APP config debe ser por medio de la IP o por nombre de la computadora + la instancia.
2. Conectar ambas computadoras en red.

Comment: Perdón por el offtopic pero con el avatar del hombre sonriente y con una mención a la caza del bueno de Yagami me has ganado por completo ;)

Comment: Ya instale SQLSERVER en la otra PC, peor sigue sin abrir, ¿Porque?

Comment: ¿Cómo es tu cadena de conexión?